# Import dump to MySQL

Tags: support, data-dump

I was able to import the [Super User](http://superuser.com) dump using SODDI earlier, but somehow I am not able to do that for the latest September dump.

Is there a better way of importing the dumps to my MySQL database?

I have a Windows 7 / Apache / PHP / MySQL stack. I am not proficient in any technologies other than PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Would probably help if you went into more detail about *how* you're not able to do that. Also, you should probably post [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/2511/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-sql-server-2000-2005-2008-sqlite-mysq) so the author gets some notification.